# Java: Access Modifier Confusion

Tags: java

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) tutorial in the Java documentation, public members can be accessed on the Class, Package, Sublcass, and World levels. But say I create two classes like so:

```
public class TesterClass
{
    public int someNumber = 5;
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
         System.out.println( someNumber );
    }
}
```

and save them in the same location. When `AnotherClass` is compiled, an error is thrown saying that the variable `someNumber` cannot be recognized. Why, then, does the Java docs state that public access modifiers allow access everywhere? I understand that I am doing something wrong, but what *exactly* is going on?

Comment: What if I also have another class with a field called `someNumber`. Which `someNumber` should `someNumber` refer to? Do you know what instance fields are? Do you know what class fields are? Do you know what scope is? (Those are all keywords to look up.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with fields (variables) and scope, I just didn't understand what I was doing wrong (not creating instances and trying to access the variables via dot notation). I see now. Thank you! Also, @RamanSB thank you as well, your examples helped.

Comment: @AleksandrH, the table in the official tutorial isn't very pedagogical imo. Have a look at [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052). Even though it doesn't address your exact question, it clarifies the scopes a bit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two classes are not related in any way, shape, or form.

You need to create an instance of the `TesterClass` in `AnotherClass`, then access the variable via the reference.

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
         TesterClass classRef = new TesterClass();
         System.out.println(classRef.someNumber);
    }
}
```

This will work and produce an output of 5.

However, if we changed the access modifier of the count variable from `public` to `private` and then attempted to do the same thing, this would no longer work. The count variable would be inaccessible to any other class except the class that declares it.

---

To expand upon Sotirios Delimanolis's comment, consider the following Scenario:

```
public class TesterClass
    {
        public int someNumber = 5;
    }

    public class CounterExampleClass
    {
        public int someNumber = 3;
    }

    public class AnotherClass
    {
        public static void main( String [] args )
        {
             System.out.println( someNumber );
        }
    }
```

According to your logic, what would be printed 3 or 5? You cannot say.
Hence the variables are accessed via a reference variable, the reference class indicates which fields can be accessed. I.e.

```
    TesterClass tRef = new TesterClass();
    tRef.someNumber; //5

    CounterExampleClass cRef = new CounterExampleClass();
    cRef.someNumber; //3
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable you referencing is bound to bring errors as it is not recongised in that class, create first an instance of TesterClass

```
    TesterClass testObj=new TesterClass();
//then call println 
System.out.println(testObj.someNumber);
```

Never use variables you havent declared!!...Happy coding